# C# AES - Padding is Invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I have been struggling with this problem for several days now.  I have read all the posts out there about this padding issue - which can often be caused by an incorrect key (possibly the case here - but I'm not seeing it.

Code Below:

```
internal class AESEncryptionManager
{
    private byte[] keyBytes { get; set; }

    private byte[] ivBytes { get; set; }

    private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[]
        {0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x12, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x02, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c};

    private Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyDerivationFunction { get; set; }
    private AesManaged aesManaged;

    public AESEncryptionManager(string key)
    {   
        aesManaged = new AesManaged();
        aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, SALT);

        aesManaged.KeySize = 256;
        aesManaged.BlockSize = 128;

        byte[] newKey = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] newIv = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.BlockSize >> 3);

        keyBytes = newKey;
        ivBytes = newIv;

        aesManaged.Key = keyBytes;
        aesManaged.IV = ivBytes;

    }

    public byte[] EncryptToBytes(byte[] message)
    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                csEncrypt.Close();
                return msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] DecryptToBytes(byte[] message)
    {
        byte[] newKey = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] newIv = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.BlockSize >> 3);

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(newKey, newIv);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csDecrypt.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                csDecrypt.Close();
                return msDecrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried the usual things like flushing the stream, etc.  Any help not already provided on MSDN or Stack Overflow would be helpful.

Comment: It seems you forgot to mention the actual issue.

Comment: The problem is that calling the decryption method on a message encrypted with the encryption method throws the exception mentioned in the question.

Comment: Dumb question.... Is the `CryptoStream` disposed/flushed *before* the byte array is prepared in `msEncrypt.ToArray()`?

Comment: @Jon Yes - the problem is that calling the decryption method on a message encrypted with the encryption method throws the exception: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: Hi jww - unfortunately - no - I tried reordering the code so that the msDecrypt.ToArray(); call comes before the close would - to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `DecryptToBytes()`.

```
byte[] newKey = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.KeySize >> 3);
byte[] newIv = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(aesManaged.BlockSize >> 3);

ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(newKey, newIv);
```

You are creating the decryptor with a different key and initialization vector than you used for encryption; you are requesting new bytes from the same key derivation function you used for deriving the key and initialization vector for encryption. Because encryption and decryption keys don't match decryption yields corrupted data and especially corrupted padding. Replace the three lines with the following one and it will work.

```
ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor();
```

Note that I did not look any closer at the code and "it will work" only means that this bug will be resolved, it does not imply that other parts of the implementation are okay, too.

Comment: Hi Daniel - According to this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx  rfc289derivebytes should give the SAME bytes with the same salt and key as input.  I did change my code as you suggested, with the same error resulting.  This is not the problem, but thank you for answering.

Comment: I made the change myself and it works here. The key derivation function will produce the same stream of bytes for the same key and salt, but you are first reading a couple of bytes for encryption in the constructor and later reading more bytes for decryption. Actually every call to the decryption method uses a different key. Just have a look at the encryption and decryption keys in the debugger and you will see that they are different.

Comment: I am going to give this one to Daniel - because when this class is run in isolation without anything else going on - his fix does work.  It does not fix my problem in the code-base, but I built a test program with just this class and it works.  I will try to narrow down where my problem is stemming from and maybe ask again in another question.

Comment: When it works in isolation but not in context I guess you are still using it with different keys for encryption and decryption. Have a look at the constructor calls and see what the used keys are.