# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed error while using AES Managed class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, encryption

I am trying to use AES 256 Encryption in windows phone for a definite key and IV to decrypt the string which I received from server. On the server side AES256/CBC/PkCS5 padding is used and I am using AES managed class of windows code.

I am getting following error:

Padding is invalid and cannot be removed error while using AES Managed class

Can you please give your valuable suggestions?

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22945303/3326331) see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have correct padding mode set on your cipher (just an example, check your encryption padding):

```
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126; // example
```

Also you don't need to set KeySize as long as you set the Key. Setting the KeySize will override your existing Key. So, just remove this line in your code:

```
        aesDecryptor.KeySize = 256;
```

Comment: In windows phone there is no PaddingMode option.The defaults PadiingMode is PKCS7

Answer (score 0):

You will sometimes get a message about invalid padding when encryption and decryption for whatever reason have not used the same key or initialization vector. Padding is a number of bytes added to the end of your plain-text to make it up to a full number of blocks for the cipher to work on. In PKCS7 padding each byte is equal to the number of bytes added, so it can always be removed after decryption. Your decryption has led to a string where the last n bytes are not equal to the value n of the last byte (hope that sentence makes sense). So try double checking  your keys.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to decrypt string. I have applied HexStringToByte Conversion instead of StringToBytes Conversion.

Many thanks for inputs.